# A Gerund or Participial Phrase?

Tags: gerunds, participial-phrases

> The state's ACLU branch reached out to the Massachusetts State Police requesting records regarding the acquisition and use of robotics.

Should there be a comma before "requesting" ?
Is the "requesting" phrase a gerund or participial ?
What does it modify ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comma, so it's clear it's ACLU not the police doing the requesting.  I'd say *requesting* is a participle modifying "branch".